# Translating features from xml to java

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-layout

Basically I'm trying to dynamically add buttons when I click another button

When I click the "Add a Class" button I would like the "Math button to appear above it like so: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9YrC.jpg) , the "Math" button is just an example of what it should look like, it is not programmed dynamically.

Currently, when I click the "Add a Class" button, this is what happens: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMd01.jpg)

I would like the dynamically added button in this case "New button" to look identical to "Math"

Here is my xml layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#7BEDFC" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/classesLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Classes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bExample"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightarrow"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text=" Math"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Add a Class"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Roundedcorners drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="10dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"  />            
 </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="10dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>       
 </shape>
</item>  
<item >
<shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="10dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
 android:endColor="#FFFFFF" />            
 </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Relevant part of activity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

LinearLayout buttonsLayout; 
Button addClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.classesLayout);

    addClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClass);
    addClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button newButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

            newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedcorners);
            newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rightarrow);

            newButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.LEFT);
            newButton.setText("New button");

            buttonsLayout.addView(newButton, buttonsLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `newButton.setCompoundDrawables(0, 0, R.drawable.rightarrow, 0);` instead of the second call to `setBackgroundResource`. If it doesn't look quite right or doesn't show the icon, you might also try `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.rightarrow, 0)`.

**EDIT**

You can still use XML for these buttons. Make an XML file (let's call it "my_button.xml") with the following:

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightarrow"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Then you can write

```
addClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Button newButton = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_button, buttonsLayout, false);
        newButton.setText("New button");
        buttonsLayout.addView(newButton, buttonsLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

    } 
});
```

Comment: Okay I got that part thanks! How about setting the size and margins/paddings? Also I need a way to make it dip instead of pixels